# program failed. sharedPtr vector c++

Tags: c++, vector

**PLEASE, i realy need help.. don't panic from the sharedPtr implementation** 

I'm having a problem with my project in c++.
In my project, I'm creating a company which holds all the information about its employees (artist, programmer,manager), projects ,...
for holding all the employees I use a vector of SharedPtr(use own Implementation)

and it seems like the vector is doing some problem:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00CC8CA9 in projComp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000044.

and pointing me to this break point in vector-

```
bool _Inside(const value_type *_Ptr) const
    {   // test if _Ptr points inside vector
    return (_Ptr < this->_Mylast && this->_Myfirst <= _Ptr);
    }
```

this is my SharedPtr implementation:

```
#ifndef _SHARED_PTR_H_
#define _SHARED_PTR_H_

#include "RCObject.h"

template<class T>
class SharedPtr {

public:
    SharedPtr(T* realPtr = 0);
    SharedPtr(const SharedPtr& rhs);
    ~SharedPtr();

    SharedPtr& operator=(const SharedPtr& rhs);
    const T* operator->() const;
    T* operator->();
    const T& operator*() const;
    T& operator*();

    template<class newType>           // template function for   
    operator SharedPtr<newType>()      // implicit conversion ops.   
    {     
        return SharedPtr<newType>(counter->pointee);
    }

private:
    struct CountHolder : public RCObject {
        ~CountHolder() { delete pointee; }
        void addReference() {
            ++refCount;
        }
        void removeReference() {
            if (--refCount == 0)delete this;
        }
        T *pointee;
    };

    CountHolder *counter;
    void init();
    void makeCopy();
};


template <class T>
void SharedPtr<T>::init() {
    if (counter->isShareable() == false) {
        T *oldValue = counter->pointee;
        counter = new CountHolder;
        counter->pointee = new T(*oldValue);
    }
    counter->addReference();
}

template <class T>
SharedPtr<T>::SharedPtr(T* realPtr) : counter(new CountHolder) {
    counter->pointee = realPtr;
    init();
}

template <class T>
SharedPtr<T>::SharedPtr(const SharedPtr& rhs) : counter(rhs.counter) {
    init();
}

template <class T>
SharedPtr<T>::~SharedPtr() {
    counter->removeReference();
}

template <class T>
SharedPtr<T>& SharedPtr<T>::operator=(const SharedPtr& rhs) {
    if (counter != rhs.counter)    {
        counter->removeReference();
        counter = rhs.counter; 
        init();
    }
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
void SharedPtr<T>::makeCopy() {
    if (counter->isShared()) {
        T *oldValue = counter->pointee;
        counter->removeReference();
        counter = new CountHolder;
        counter->pointee = new T(*oldValue);
        counter->addReference();
    }
}

template <class T>
const T* SharedPtr<T>::operator->() const {
    return counter->pointee;
}

template <class T>
T* SharedPtr<T>::operator->() {
    makeCopy();
    return counter->pointee;
}

template <class T>
const T& SharedPtr<T>::operator*() const {
    return *(counter->pointee);
}

template <class T>
T& SharedPtr<T>::operator*() {
    makeCopy();
    return *(counter->pointee);
}

#endif
```

and this is RCObject:

```
#ifndef _RCOBJ_H_
#define _RCOBJ_H_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class RCObject {
//private:
protected:
    int refCount;
    bool shareable;

protected:
    RCObject();
    RCObject(const RCObject&);
    virtual ~RCObject() = 0;

    RCObject& operator=(const RCObject&);

public:
    virtual void addReference() = 0;
    virtual void removeReference() = 0;
    void markUnshareable();
    bool isShareable() const;
    bool isShared() const;

};

#endif
```

and its implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "RCObject.h"
using namespace std;


RCObject::RCObject() : refCount(0), shareable(true) {
}

RCObject::RCObject(const RCObject&) : refCount(0), shareable(true) {
}

RCObject& RCObject::operator=(const RCObject&) {
    return *this;
}

RCObject::~RCObject() {
}

void RCObject::addReference() {
    ++refCount;
}

void RCObject::removeReference() {
    if (--refCount == 0) delete this;
}

void RCObject::markUnshareable() {
    shareable = false;
}

bool RCObject::isShareable() const {
    return shareable;
}

bool RCObject::isShared() const {
    return refCount > 1;
}
```

the problem is with this code line:

```
void Company::addArtist(vector<string> empAfield, string idCmp, string currPrj, double currPrjHrs, double ttlHrs, double exp, bool isEmp, double hrsDay, string name, string lastName, string idPrsn, long phoneNum) {
    _employeeList.push_back(SharedPtr<Artist>(new Artist(empAfield, idCmp, currPrj, currPrjHrs, ttlHrs, exp, isEmp, hrsDay, name, lastName, idPrsn, phoneNum)));
}
```

sorry for the long code, I struggle thinking what can made this problem.
maybe the vector deleting the SharedPtr after its already freed?
It's not supposed to be, but i run out of idea.

thanks for everyone who tries to redeem my misery ;)

Comment: You should have a pretty good reason to reimplement a shared pointer as there is std::shared_ptr or boost::shared_ptr widely available.

Comment: it's mandatory by the course's professor.

Comment: It looks like your `RCObject::operator=` doesn't do what it should. It just returns `*this`. It doesn't actually handle the assignment. I'm not sure if that's what's causing your crash though.

Comment: @Noa Ok, that's a pretty good reason :-)

Comment: The error location is 0x00000044, which usually means that 'this' was NULL in the method call, while it is trying to access a variable (at location this+0x44 in this case). Is the 'Company' instance not NULL before you call addArtist?

Comment: @davmac know it looks weird but RCObject is just the base class and it doesn't hold any value (like counter)

Comment: @birdypme WOW!! you're genius :D
thank you SO MUCH.. 
i searched all over the internet for hours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error location is 0x00000044, which usually means that `this` was NULL in the method call, while it is trying to access a member variable (at location `this+0x44` in this case).

Check that you are not calling `addArtist()` on a NULL `Company*` pointer.